# Creating table in which with primary key is combination of two fields in two different table

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to create table which contains primary key which has fields of two different tables.

**URL_TABLE**

```
---------            
url varchar(255)    No           
desc    varchar(2048)   No           
preview varchar(255)    No           
img_url varchar(128)    No           
title   varchar(128)    No           
hash    varchar(128)    No       // This is one  
rate    varchar(20)     Yes     NULL
```

**USER**

```
------
id      varchar(40) No       //This is 2nd
name    varchar(50) Yes     NULL         
email   varchar(50) Yes     NULL         
picture varchar(50) No
```

**Query:**

```
create table post_table as 
    select id 
    from USER 
  UNION 
    select url, desc, preview, img_url, title, hash, rate 
    from URL_TABLE 
primary key (id,hash);
```

Is this a correct query?

Comment: I only have one question... why?

Comment: @Napolux OP got you there.

Comment: Well, I think this make no sense. You can create 1 table with all the fields and the two fields as primary key or in a proper ER "schema" I would create a relation between the two tables, so there's no need for a shared primary key.

Comment: "You can create 1 table with all the fields and the two fields as primary key " this is what I have done and want to do

Comment: @Programming_crazy what's the difference between url table and post table?

Comment: @Programming_crazy Can you clarify your intent by providing a few rows of sample data for both tables and a desired outcome for `post_table` based on the sample data provided?

Comment: I think userid in URL table confused you. Well see my updated question.

My purpose is on my page I have user's running session(which will give me his ID) and I want to bind his action on each URL he processed. 

So post_table will contains id from user table and rest fields from url table

Comment: @peterm: can you understand requirement?

Comment: @Programming_crazy Sorry, unfortunately it's hardly decipherable

Comment: requirements aside, when you run a union query, both halves have to have the same number of fields, and the same data type for each corresponding field.

Comment: @Programming_crazy. The thing i don't understand is your UNION query. After making it the same number of columns from both tables, you would end up with rows with only ID and the rest NULL, and the rows from URL_TABLE with no ID. If you want to JOIN them, you have to have a method to do that. Is the id always the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From this comment, "My purpose is on my page I have user's running session(which will give me his ID) and I want to bind his action on each URL he processed. So post_table will contains id from user table and rest fields from url table"

You are describing a many to many relationship between users and urls.  A user can process more than one url and a url can be processed by more than one user.

A better way to store this data would be with a table that had the user_id, url, and datetime_processed as the primary key.  You can get other information about the url from the url table with a simple join.

Comment: My comment to the actual question explained the requirements of union queries.